# Stereo Extended Ball Gag setup

Tags: rycote

Hi all,

Being my first question here I would like to introduce myself. I am Nikhil Varma.

I am planning to buy a Stereo Extended Ball gag for the Sennheiser 8040 Stereo set. By looking at the dimensions of the Stereo extended ball gag it seems that fitting both the microphones with their XLR modules while positioned XY at 120 deg would be quite difficult. It seems that most people don't use the XLR modules but instead use the Sennheiser remote cables. Now my questions are:

1) Is it possible to fit the microphones in the windshield with their XLR modules in an XY position at 120 deg? Has anyone tried

2) If not, Is there a product like a Stereo Extended MZL suspension where the two short remote cables go into the Connbox and comes out as a 5 pin XLR? (In fact, I should mail this to Rycote, but still)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from Rycote yesterday. They say

"We are just about to introduce a stereo Connbox with two detachable MZL, 130 mm tails. The product code & price is listed below.

Description:        Connbox Stereo MZL
Part No:            016926
Retail Price:       199.79 GBP exc. VAT

This Connbox will be a special order item, with a 2 week lead time."

Hope this will be helpful for atleast some.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just received word from my dealer that the stereo Rycote MZL Connbox will have a US price of $468, with a 6-8 week lead time. That is crazy expensive, and much more than the US equivalent of 200 pounds. Wondering why...

Answer (score 2):

I own a pair of MKH8040s that live in an extended stereo ball gag and can tell you definitively that they will not fit inside with the XLR modules attached (especially at 120); you absolutely have to use the remote MZL cables.

[image: Rycote Extended Ball Gag with MKH8040s in 90 config]
<sub>(source: [noisekitchen.com](http://www.noisekitchen.com/pics/Rycote_Stereo_Extended.JPG))</sub>

However, Rycote seem to be teasing that a stereo connbox will soon be available with MZL tails through some recent posts to their facebook page.  I suggest that you contact them directly and find out what their plans are.

If you do find anything, please post back!  We'd all love to hear it.

Comment: @Scott Petersen Thanks Scott. From the picture above I suppose that your setup is  made up of a mono extension suspension(040107), XY-MS Mount(048426) and naturally the windshield. By the way, I have emailed Rycote about the connbox. I shall get back as they reply.

Comment: I got a confirmation from Rycote that they are indeed in the process of making a Stereo MZF connbox.


Answer (score 0):

Nikhil,

You might try the [Rycote Baby Ball Gag](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/322363-REG/Rycote_011001_Baby_Ball_Gag_Windshield.html) windscreens. These are individual mini-blimp attachments for smaller-diaphragm condensers. It fits only over the front of the mic (making it useless for shotguns), but if you bought one for each 8040 then you could position the two mics however you see fit using a stereo bar. Rycote also sells a [windjammer](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/322367-REG/Rycote_021801_Windjammer_for_Baby_Ball.html) to go with the baby ball gag.

Good luck!

~Matt

Comment: Doesn't work very well I'm afraid, the mics gets way to far away from each other to work in a X/Y-configuration. Tried that myself a few years ago, and the downmix to mono phased a lot no matter what I did. Work great for A-B though.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Seems like it might be too big for the 8040s on second look.